# Cannot access javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, undefined

I have a function in a factory which returns an array (highestEd is an array defined above).

```
dataService.listHighestEd = function(){
    return highestEd;
}
```

When I store returned value into a $scope variable, and use ng-repeat, it works fine. However, when I store it in a $scope variable and try to access an element from it, it says it's undefined.

```
$scope.education = dataService.listHighestEd();
if ($scope.education[0] == "College"){
    //Do Stuff
}
```

I have used console.log($scope.education) and I can see the array filled with the data and it has a length of 102, however if I do console.log($scope.education.length) it returns 0 or console.log($scope.education[0]) returns undefined.

I have no idea why this is happening as when I use ng-repeat over the same array in the UI, it accesses the information perfectly.

Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated as it's very important for my upcoming deadline.

Below is an image of the code being run and the output to the console. The contents of the array are visible along the bottom, yet the array.length is coming up as 0.

[image: Image of controller being run and output in the console.]

Comment: This is not enough information to diagnose your problem. Can you post a demo reproducing the issue?

Comment: can you show some more code.. or create a jsbin here. http://jsbin.com/?html,console,output

Comment: In JS you don't need to have a value for index 0 in the array, when you console.log the array, do you see [0: "some data", 1: "some other data"] and so on, or is index 0 actually undefined?

Comment: Here is a jsbin but it's not fully working as I've imported various classes. 

http://jsbin.com/dujudatajo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I had a look at the code in the jsbin that you posted, and I think it might be a timing problem, but it was some time since I used Angular and the $q promises library.